# How to determine parameters for the generic PL/SQL procedure (executes a group by clause)?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I would like to create a generic Oracle PL/SQL Procedure which takes table name and column name as a parameter and then creates group by SQL againts the table name. Then basic structre of my procedure is this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_GROUPBY (
      P_Table_Name     IN ,
      P_Column_Name    IN ,
   )
   BEGIN
      /**********************Check Parameters ************************/

      IF (P_Table_Name IS NULL OR P_Column_Name IS NULL)
      THEN
         Raise_Application_Error (-20001, 'Parameter cannot be NULL');
      END IF;

      /**********************Select statment ************************/

      SELECT P_Column_Name, COUNT(*) AS CNT
      FROM P_Table_Name
      GROUP BY P_Column_Name
      ORDER BY P_Column_Name;

   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         ROLLBACK;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line ('Cannot run the statement');
         Raise_Application_Error (-20004,
                                  'Could not run the procedure: ' || SQLERRM);
   END P_GROUPBY;
```

How to determine the data type for the parameters? How this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot issue SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT P_Column_Name, COUNT(*) AS CNT
  FROM P_Table_Name
  GROUP BY P_Column_Name
  ORDER BY P_Column_Name;
```

The solution is to use dynamic sql:

```
v_sql := 'SELECT ' || P_Column_Name || ', COUNT(*) AS CNT' ||
'FROM ' || P_Table_Name ||
'GROUP BY ' || P_Column_Name ||
'ORDER BY ' || P_Column_Name;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
```

Regarding `How to determine the data type for the parameters?` I am not sure what you mean. May be you want to determine the type of specific column in a table? If yes then you could query `USER_TAB_COLS` view:

```
select data_type from user_tab_cols 
 where table_name = P_Table_Name
   and column_name = P_Column_Name;
```

One more addition: you don't need `ROLLBACK` in exception handling part as long as you don't modify any data in your procedure.

Comment: Thanks, I meant that in procedure I have these parameter descriptions: P_Table_Name IN <what I put here>, P_Column_Name    IN <what I put here>. What is the data type that should be after IN clause?

Comment: @jrara Usually `varchar2` is used for string values in PL/SQL: `P_Table_Name IN varchar2`.